# How to close the terminal when running a tornado application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, tornado

I am running Python tornado web application from terminal by typing the command `python app.py` when I close the terminal, the app stops. Is there anyway I can still run the app on a port such that closing terminal wouldn't affect it? Because I don't want to keep the terminal open.

Answer (score 1):

Try `nohup`. In your case, it should be sufficient to run:

```
nohup python app.py &
```

Take note of the number shown as result of this command; it is the pid of the process, and it is used to terminate the process itself, simply by killing it. Suppose that 3456 is the pid of the process, so this command will terminate your application:

```
kill -9 3456
```

In case you lose the pid, it can be retrieved using this command:

```
ps -A | grep app.py
```

where `app.py` is the Python script file (the same used in the initial nohup command).

Anyway, for further information you can take a look [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm).